# mybatis @UpdateProvider returns #{ddd} error in the field value of sql

Tags: mybatis

UpdateProvider corresponding method returns sql field value contains #{id} error

```
    @UpdateProvider(type=SQLProvider.class, method="update")
    List<Map<String, Object>> update(DBean reqBean);

     public String update(DBean reqBean){
    return "UPDATE TBL_ARTICLE" + 
    "SET TITLE='', DESCRIPTION='kkk #{ID}  kkk', GROUP_ID='', USER_ID='', TAGS=''" + 
    "HERE (ID = '157175905347841')"
}
```

> org.apache.ibatis.reflection.ReflectionException: There is no getter
>   for property named 'ID' in 'class com.xs.jdbc.mybatis.bean.DBean'

Comment: And what is you question?

Comment: The string "#{ID}" is the field I want to write to the database, but mybatis is going to parse it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably, you can resolve by append escape character(`\` = backslash) .
Could you try change to `DESCRIPTION='kkk \\#{ID}  kkk'` instead of `DESCRIPTION='kkk #{ID}  kkk'`?